# Spring Data JPA/REST Update subcollection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a Spring Data Jpa/Rest web application.

I have created two entities, A and B, where entity A contains multiple B entities.

The DTO classes are defined as:

Getters/Setters are omitted.

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private List<B> b = new LinkedList<>();
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String bType;
}
```

The Respective repositories extend PagingAndSortingReposity.

At the moment, to create a record of type A, I create a collection of links to its subentities (namely Bs). It works fine, but when I attempt to update a record I find that using the same method updates only the first level of the json and the rest remains unchanged.

My question is: how to update entity A together with a new collection of entities B.

Comment: You should set the cascade type : https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/
For example : `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: Yes, I have already added it. It is supposed to create the B entities automatically when they are added to A from what I understand. However, I am unable to create them in such a way. This is why I first had to create each of them separately and then pass an array of links to the B entities when create the A.

Comment: I've set up a test to simulate your case and it seems to work. Is your repository extending a `JpaRepository` (or just `PagingAndSortingRepository`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching, I received a help from a mentor and internet.

Since I am working with association resource it fails to do the task in such a way. The backend Java application seems to be configured correctly.

To update the content of the application one needs to set the content-type to text/uri-list as listed in [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource) and simply send a string with link to each subobject.

Answer (score 0):

Class A has onetomany mapping

so in Class b there must be manytoone simeting like this

```
@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne
private A aID;
```

If you add these lines 
and add `CascadeType.ALL`  in `@ManyToOne`

and merge parent entity changes are getting reflected to child table also.

Comment: If he does not need bidirectional relationship, it is not necessary to have a `ManyToOne` on the non-owning side.